# How to prove these picture is same configuration

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I would like to prove that after shifting 1 unit vertically, the picture a) becomes the picture b), then c). The matrix for a, b and c are bellow the picture. Could you please help?

```
a = [[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2]], [[1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3]]]
shift_matrix = []
shift_unit_a = 0
shift_unit_b = 1
for item in a:
    for u in range(1, 3):
        shift_matrix[u][0] = item[u][0] + shift_unit_a
        shift_matrix[u][1] = item[u][1] + shift_unit_b
        if (np.array_equal(np.array(shift_matrix), np.array(item[u]))
            shift = 1
            print "True"
        else:
            shift = 0
            print "False"
```

Could you please help me?[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to detect any shift or only vertical up by one?

Comment: I'd like to keep origin picture and delete the others if shifting is true. if shifting are false, I like to keep all.

Comment: The answer to your question depends on the answer to my question. Are you looking for any parallel shift or only exactly one pixel up?

Comment: yes, I want detect any shift, but I think it is complicated. Then I think I should start first with vertical direction. But if you can help me with any shift, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It boils down to detecting whether all the points of one set are shifted the same way from their counterpart in another set.

```
def is_shift(set1, set2): 
    shift = None  # will store a tuple of delta_x, delta_y
    for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in zip(set1, set2): 
        cur_shift = x1 - x1, y1 - y2 
        if not shift:  # the first pair of points
            shift = cur_shift 
        elif shift != cur_shift: # shifted the same way as the first one?
            return False 
    return True
```

```
>>> is_shift([[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2]])
True  
>>> is_shift([[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3]])
False
```

Now, that since "set1 is a shifted set2" is a transitive relation, it's enough to run `is_shifted` between the first set and each of the remaining ones.

There is a caveat though. Depending on your assumptions about the data, you may want to make sure that the points are ordered the same way, i.e. sort each set in advance.

I think there can be a more efficient implementation with a clever use of `numpy`, but the idea will be the same.

Comment: Thank you so much! it work well for shifting all. May I ask the case if some, not all points are shifted?

Comment: @BinhThien this requires a better definition. Like, how many points are enough to match etc. It feels the algorithm will be way more sophisticated.

Comment: I like to delete the member of list which is shifted, but get wrong. Could you please help?  ```a = [[(1, 1), (2, 1)], [(3, 1), (1, 2)], [(3, 3), (4, 3)], [(4, 5), (3, 3)]]
for i in range(0, len(a)):
 for j in range(1, len(a)):
  if (i<j):
   if (is_shift(a[i], a[j])==True):
    a.remove(a[j])
   else:
    print(a[i])
    print(a[j])```

Comment: @BinhThien please ask a new question, these margins are too narrow.

Comment: Please check <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59101782/delete-the-shifted-elements>